# When <body> used with margin and background image

Tags: html, css

When used with `margin` and `background-image`, normal `<div>` and `<body>` behaves quite differently.

Normal `<div>` works as expected (`margin` is not part of the content, thus no background image appears in the `margin`):

```css
div {
  background: url("http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_flwr.gif");
  background-size: auto;
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 40px;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:60px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>Original image: <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_flwr.gif" alt="Flowers" width="224" height="162" /></p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The background-size property is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>
</div>
```

However, `margin` seems to be part of the content when it comes to `<body>` and the background image appears in the margin, which is unexpected:

```css
body {
  background: url("http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_flwr.gif");
  background-size: auto;
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 40px;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:60px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>Original image: <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_flwr.gif" alt="Flowers" width="224" height="162" /></p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The background-size property is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't set a background on the `<html>` element, the background of the body element is propagated to the canvas. If you don't want that, just set a background to the html element.

i.e. `html { background-color: white; }`

Formally, the [CSS spec says](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/colors.html#background)

> ... For documents whose root element is an HTML "HTML" element or an XHTML "html" element that has computed values of 'transparent' for 'background-color' and 'none' for 'background-image', user agents must instead use the computed value of the background properties from that element's first HTML "BODY" element or XHTML "body" element child when painting backgrounds for the canvas, and must not paint a background for that child element. Such backgrounds must also be anchored at the same point as they would be if they were painted only for the root element.

```css
html {
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  background: url("http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_flwr.gif");
  background-size: auto;
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 40px;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:60px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>Original image: <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_flwr.gif" alt="Flowers" width="224" height="162" /></p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The background-size property is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the real reason behind this error but got a tricky solution.
give this to your css

```
      background-position: top 70px left 70px;//change the value as you want
```

*css*

```
body {
  background: url("http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_flwr.gif");
  background-size: auto;
  background-position: top 70px left 70px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 40px;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:60px;
}
```